# How to include jquery.validate.js file (in the local directory) and use it in the validation of form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I know that including`<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>` will do the trick, but I'm not able to find out anywhere that how it can be done after downloading the file `jquery.validate.js` and paste it in local directory.

I tried it by pasting `jquery.validate.js` file in the same directory as the validation file and using : `<script src="jquery.validate.js"></script>`, but it didn't work.

The validation code is in register.phtml file and the **script** portion of it is:

```js
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // validate signup form on keyup and submit
        $("#registerForm").validate({
            rules: {
                first_name: "required",
                last_name: "required",
                contact_no: {
                    required: true,
                    digits: true,
                    minlength: 10,
                    maxlength: 13,
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true,
                },
                invitation_code: {
                    required: true,
                },
            },
            messages: {
                first_name: "Please enter your First Name",
                last_name: "Please enter your Last Name",
                contact_no: {
                    required: "Please enter your Contact Number",
                    digits: "Please enter only digits(0-9)",
                    minlength: "Minimum 10 digits are required",
                    maxlength: "Maximum 13 digits are allowed",
                },
                email: {
                    required: "Please enter a valid Email address",
                    email: "Your email address must be in the format of name@domain",
                },
                invitation_code: {
                    required: "Please check your email for Invitation Code",
                },
               
            }
        });
        $("#email").keypress(function () {
            $('.error_msg1').hide();
        });
        $('#invitationCode').click(function () {
            document.getElementById('invitation').innerHTML = "";
        });
        $("#first_name").on('keyup', function(e) {
                var val = $(this).val();
                if (val.match(/[^a-zA-Z]/g)) {
                  $(this).val(val.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, ''));
                }
        });
        $("#last_name").on('keyup', function(e) {
                var val = $(this).val();
                if (val.match(/[^a-zA-Z]/g)) {
                  $(this).val(val.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, ''));
                }
        });
        
        $('#submitform').click(function () {
        if (!$('#Check_TermsAndCondidation').prop('checked'))
            {
                $('#Check_TermsAndCondidation_msg').html('Please check Terms and Conditions');
                return false;
            }
        });
        
        $('#Check_TermsAndCondidation').change( function(){
            $('#Check_TermsAndCondidation_msg').html('');
        });
    });
</script>
```

The above snippet is validating properly but after editing the first line of above code to :
`<script src="jquery.validate.js"></script>` , it doesn't work.

Comment: If you want us to help you figure out what's going wrong, you'll need to show us the relevant HTML code.

Comment: If you're using the correct syntax (see my edits), it SHOULD work if you put your JS in the same directory as your HTML file. If you believe your syntax is correct but it still isn't working, check whether the file permissions of your JS file are OK ("others" need at least some access). If file permissions are OK, you'll need to show us more code for us to be able to figure out what else could be wrong.

Comment: @John Slegers, i have added the script portion also.

Comment: Please follow this procedure : (1) replace `http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js` with `jquery.validate.js` (2) open your page in Google Chrome (3) right-click on your webpage and select `view source` (4) right-click on `jquery.validate.js` in your source and select `open link in new tab` (5) copy-paste the URL of the page you just opened in a reply to this comment.

Comment: http://geeekin.localhost/jquery.validate.js

Comment: Could you give me the local path (on your server) of your `register.phtml` file?

Comment: You can see it here: http://www.geeekin.com/register, its live code actually.

Comment: I just posted an answer with an explanation of what (I'm pretty sure) is wrong. If anything in that answer confuses you or simply doesn't work for you, please comment on my answer and I'll try to help you further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is almost certainly this : you put your file in the wrong directory.

Assuming your website is using PHP (most likely) and Apache, the location of your `jquery.validate.js` file should be relative to the root folder of your website on your server. That is the folder that corresponds with `localhost`. This is typically `/var/www`, but it really depends on your server settings.

Assuming you're using PHP, the exact folder the location of your file needs to be relative to probably contains a file named `index.php` and a file named `.htaccess`.

IF the root folder of your website on your server is `/var/www`, you should probably also see a folder named  `/var/www/js`. In that case, the proper thing to do is put your `jquery.validate.js` file in the folder `/var/www/js` and add it to your `register.phtml` file like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

If you're confused about any of these steps, please let me know in the comments and I'll try to help you further with whatever steps you might find confusing.

Comment: Thanks Sir, it sorted the problem :)

Comment: Just for my curiosity, i wanted to know what jquery.validate.min file is about (some people use it).

Comment: @apprentice : jQuery.validate is a jQuery plugin supposed to make clientside form validation easy. You can find the official docs @ http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

1. go to [this page](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js)
2. select all code
3. copy that code
4. create a file named `jquery.validate.js` in the same directory of your HTML file and paste the code there
5. put this script tag in your HTML file with the name of the file you created :

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hello please follow my steps and add the script locally.It works, the problem with the second script is you dont have it locally.So, follow these steps and add a file locally and then include this script.

Comment: I actually think your answer is a pretty good answer. It may be nothing but a workaround, but it's actually a pretty good workaround that SHOULD work NO MATTER what is wrong. So you're getting a +1 from me ;-)

Comment: Bro, i did already have jquery.validation.js locally, but it is not working.

Comment: is that the same file as the other which you copied?

Comment: Yes, i copied it from http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js, as u said.

Comment: @apprentice : IF the problem is caused by eg. file permission errors, Sravan's solution should work. However, the problem is probably caused by something else.

Comment: Yes, the solution provided by John Slegers worked. Also voted up for ur answer. Thanks bro

Comment: No problem bro. Have a good day. But some one who down voted this should know that this is a relevant answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a js folder which will keep all javascript files. Place `jquery.validate.js` in that directory. Now to include that in project depends which framework/MVC system you are using. Say you are using laravel MVC then use it as

```
<script src="{{ Request::root() }}/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

And in case using simple php then access it using `echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];`
Basically you have to use project base url for including the file.
Hope it helps.